Generate a Penrose tiling
I would like to know if it's possible to optimize the code the generate this type of Penrose Tiling.
I finished programming this type in javascript / p5.js and the algorithm works very fine and takes 1.549 seconds on a Core i5 – 4590 (3.3 gHz) with 8 GB of RAM to generate the image below. But I would like to know if it’s possible to optimize the code so that there is more performance and takes even less time.

I even asked this when I was starting to program in another post in Stack Overflow and I used (and optimized) some suggestions made by user Linda Paiste, which was a great suggestion, but I would like to know if it is possible to optimize it further.
Here's the code:
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Penrose Tiling - P1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
  <script>

  var size = 10;
  const tolerance = 0.00001;
  const radianFactor = 3.141592653589793 / 180;
  var formVertex = {};
  var mainList = [];
  var forms = [];
  var amount = 0;

  //Each "cyan" pentagon with five rhombus (type 0) will generate two more of the same type forming a "layer" (with the exception of the first). Each time a layer is formed, the quantity is increased until the maximum quantity is reached. You can change the "maxLayerAmount" variable and higher values ​​will produce larger images, but it will take more time.
  var limit = 0;
  var layerAmount = 0;
  var maxLayerAmount = 10;

  var pentagonVertex = [];
  var rhombusVertex = [];
  var boatVextex = [];
  var starVertex = [];

class points
{
  constructor(x, y)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

function setup()
{
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) pentagonVertex[i] = new points();
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) rhombusVertex[i] = new points();
  for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) boatVextex[i] = new points();
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) starVertex[i] = new points();
  createCanvas(2000, 2000);
}

function createVertexForms(formAngles)
{
  let auxiliar = new Array(formAngles.length);
  let i;
  let previousPoint;
  auxiliar[0] = {x: formVertex.x, y: formVertex.y};
  formAngles.map((formAngles, i) => {
                                    formVertex.angle += formAngles;
                                    previousPoint = auxiliar[i];
                                    auxiliar[i + 1] = {x: previousPoint.x + size * cos(formVertex.angle * radianFactor), y: previousPoint.y + size * (-sin(formVertex.angle * radianFactor))};
                                  });
  return auxiliar;
}

function drawForm(formVertex)
{
  beginShape();
  for (let i in formVertex)
    vertex(formVertex[i].x, formVertex[i].y);
  endShape(CLOSE);
}

function draw()
{
  var startTime = performance.now();
  translate (width / 2, height / 2);
  let startAngle = 18;
  let hipotenuse = size / (2 * sin(36 * radianFactor));
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    pentagonVertex[i].x = hipotenuse * cos(startAngle * radianFactor);
    pentagonVertex[i].y = hipotenuse * (-sin(startAngle * radianFactor));
    mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[i].x, y: pentagonVertex[i].y, angle: startAngle - 18, form: 0, type: 1});
    mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[i].x, y: pentagonVertex[i].y, angle: startAngle + 162, form: 2, type: 0});
    startAngle += 72;
  }
  fill('cyan');
  drawForm(pentagonVertex);
  while ((formVertex = mainList.pop()) !== undefined)
  {
    switch (formVertex.form)
    {
      case 0: if (forms.findIndex(item => {return item.identificator === 0 && item.form.some(form => Math.abs(form.x - formVertex.x) < tolerance && Math.abs(form.y - formVertex.y) < tolerance);}) >= 0) break;
              rhombusVertex = createVertexForms([0, 36, 144]);
              if (formVertex.type > 1)
              {
                let auxiliar = forms.findIndex(item => {return item.identificator === 0 && item.form.some(form => Math.abs(form.x - rhombusVertex[1].x) < tolerance && Math.abs(form.y - rhombusVertex[1].y) < tolerance)});
                if (auxiliar >= 0)
                {
                  forms.splice(auxiliar, 1);
                  continue;
                }
                  else
                  {
                    auxiliar = forms.findIndex(item => {return item.identificator === 0 && item.form.some(form => Math.abs(form.x - rhombusVertex[3].x) < tolerance && Math.abs(form.y - rhombusVertex[3].y) < tolerance)});
                    if (auxiliar >= 0)
                    {
                      forms.splice(auxiliar, 1);
                      continue;
                    }
                  }
              }
              forms.push({form: rhombusVertex, identificator: 0});
              mainList.unshift({x: rhombusVertex[2].x, y: rhombusVertex[2].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 72, form: 1, type: formVertex.type});
              fill('yellow');
              drawForm(rhombusVertex);
      break;
      case 1: pentagonVertex = createVertexForms([72, 72, 72, 72]);
              if (formVertex.type === 0)
              {
                if (forms.findIndex(item => {return item.identificator === 1 && item.type === 0 && item.form.some(form => Math.abs(form.x - formVertex.x) < tolerance && Math.abs(form.y - formVertex.y) < tolerance)}) >= 0) 
                {
                  mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[1].x, y: pentagonVertex[1].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 72, form: 0, type: 1});
                  mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[2].x, y: pentagonVertex[2].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 144, form: 0, type: 1});
                  mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[3].x, y: pentagonVertex[3].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 216, form: 0, type: 1});
                  mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[4].x, y: pentagonVertex[4].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 288, form: 0, type: 1});
                  continue;
                }
                  else
                  {
                    if (amount === limit)
                    {
                      layerAmount++;
                      if (layerAmount > maxLayerAmount)
                      {
                        if (forms.findIndex(item => {return item.identificator === 1 && item.type === 4 && item.form.some(form => Math.abs(form.x - formVertex.x) < tolerance && Math.abs(form.y - formVertex.y) < tolerance)}) < 0)
                        {
                          fill('cyan');
                          drawForm(pentagonVertex);
                        }
                          else
                          {
                            mainList.unshift({x: formVertex.x, y: formVertex.y, angle: formVertex.angle - 36, form: 2, type: 3});
                            mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[4].x, y: pentagonVertex[4].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 252, form: 2, type: 3});
                          }
                        forms.push({form: pentagonVertex, identificator: 1, type: 4});
                        break;
                      }
                      amount = 0;
                      limit += 5;
                    }
                    amount++;
                    mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[0].x, y: pentagonVertex[0].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 180, form: 2, type: 0});
                    mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[1].x, y: pentagonVertex[1].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 252, form: 2, type: 0});
                    mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[2].x, y: pentagonVertex[2].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 324, form: 2, type: 0});
                    mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[3].x, y: pentagonVertex[3].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 36, form: 2, type: 0});
                    mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[4].x, y: pentagonVertex[4].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 108, form: 2, type: 0});
                  }
              }
                else if (formVertex.type === 1)
                {
                  mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[2].x, y: pentagonVertex[2].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 144, form: 0, type: 3});
                  mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[3].x, y: pentagonVertex[3].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 216, form: 0, type: 2});
                }
                  else if (formVertex.type === 2)
                  {
                    if ((forms.findIndex(item => {return item.identificator === 1 && item.type === 3 && item.form.some(form => Math.abs(form.x - formVertex.x) < tolerance && Math.abs(form.y - formVertex.y) < tolerance)}) >= 0)
                         || (forms.findIndex(item => {return item.identificator === 1 && item.type === 1 && item.form.some(form => Math.abs(form.x - pentagonVertex[1].x) < tolerance && Math.abs(form.y - pentagonVertex[1].y) < tolerance)}) >= 0)) continue;
                    mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[3].x, y: pentagonVertex[3].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 216, form: 0, type: 0});
                  }
                    else
                    {
                      if ((forms.findIndex(item => {return item.identificator === 1 && item.type === 2 && item.form.some(form => Math.abs(form.x - formVertex.x) < tolerance && Math.abs(form.y - formVertex.y) < tolerance)}) >= 0)
                           || (forms.findIndex(item => {return item.identificator === 1 && item.type === 1 && item.form.some(form => Math.abs(form.x - pentagonVertex[3].x) < tolerance && Math.abs(form.y - pentagonVertex[3].y) < tolerance)}) >= 0)) continue;
                      mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[2].x, y: pentagonVertex[2].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 144, form: 0, type: 0});
                    }
              forms.push({form: pentagonVertex, identificator: 1, type: formVertex.type});
              fill('cyan');
              drawForm(pentagonVertex);
      break;
      case 2: pentagonVertex = createVertexForms([72, 72, 72, 72]);
              if (formVertex.type < 4)
                if (formVertex.type === 0)
                {
                  mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[2].x, y: pentagonVertex[2].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 108, form: 3, type: 3});
                  mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[3].x, y: pentagonVertex[3].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 252, form: 4, type: 0}); // BOAT
                  mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[4].x, y: pentagonVertex[4].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 108, form: 3, type: 3});
                }
                  else
                  {
                    if (formVertex.type == 3)
                    {
                      if (forms.findIndex(item => {return item.identificator === 5 && item.form.some(form => Math.abs(form.x - pentagonVertex[2].x) < tolerance && Math.abs(form.y - pentagonVertex[2].y) < tolerance)}) < 0) continue;
                      mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[2].x, y: pentagonVertex[2].y, angle: formVertex.angle - 36, form: 3, type: 3});
                    }
                    mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[2].x, y: pentagonVertex[2].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 108, form: 3, type: formVertex.type});
                  }
              fill('gray');
              drawForm(pentagonVertex);
      break;
      case 3: pentagonVertex = createVertexForms([72, 72, 72, 72]);
              if (formVertex.type < 3)
                if (formVertex.type === 0) mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[1].x, y: pentagonVertex[1].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 108, form: 5, type: 1});
                  else if (formVertex.type === 1) mainList.unshift({x: formVertex.x, y: formVertex.y, angle: formVertex.angle + 324, form: 4, type: 1});
                    else mainList.unshift({x: pentagonVertex[3].x, y: pentagonVertex[3].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 180, form: 4, type: 1});
              fill('red');
              drawForm(pentagonVertex);
      break;
      case 4: if (formVertex.type === 0)
              {
                if (forms.findIndex(item => {return item.identificator === 5 && item.form.some(form => Math.abs(form.x - formVertex.x) < tolerance && Math.abs(form.y - formVertex.y) < tolerance)}) >= 0) continue;
                boatVextex = createVertexForms([-36, -72, 144, 36, 36, 144]);
                mainList.unshift({x: boatVextex[2].x, y: boatVextex[2].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 324, form: 2, type: 1});
                mainList.unshift({x: boatVextex[3].x, y: boatVextex[3].y, angle: formVertex.angle, form: 3, type: 0});
                mainList.unshift({x: boatVextex[5].x, y: boatVextex[5].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 324, form: 2, type: 2});
              }
                else
                {
                  if (forms.findIndex(item => {return item.identificator === 0 && item.form.some(form => Math.abs(form.x - formVertex.x) < tolerance && Math.abs(form.y - formVertex.y) < tolerance)}) >= 0) continue;
                  boatVextex = createVertexForms([36, 144, -72, 144, -72, 144]);
                  mainList.unshift({x: boatVextex[1].x, y: boatVextex[1].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 180, form: 2, type: 4});
                  mainList.unshift({x: boatVextex[2].x, y: boatVextex[2].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 324, form: 3, type: 3});
                  mainList.unshift({x: boatVextex[3].x, y: boatVextex[3].y, angle: formVertex.angle, form: 2, type: 4});
                  mainList.unshift({x: boatVextex[4].x, y: boatVextex[4].y, angle: formVertex.angle + 36, form: 3, type: 3});
                }
              fill('green');
              drawForm(boatVextex);
      break;
      default: if (forms.findIndex(item => {return item.identificator === 5 && item.form.some(form => Math.abs(form.x - (formVertex.x + size * cos((formVertex.angle + 72) * radianFactor))) < tolerance && Math.abs(form.y - (formVertex.y + size * (-sin((formVertex.angle + 72) * radianFactor)))) < tolerance)}) >= 0) continue;
               starVertex = createVertexForms([72, -72, 144, -72, 144, -72, 144, -72, 144]);
               forms.push({form: starVertex, identificator: 5});
               fill('orange');
               drawForm(starVertex);
    }
  }
  var finalTime = performance.now();
  console.log("Time spent: " + ((finalTime - startTime) / 1000) + " seconds.");
  forms.splice(0, forms.length);
  noLoop();
}
  </script>
  </body>
</html>


I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per site goals: "State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Can you elaborate on the combinations of form / type for formVertex? For example, I can see that the cyan pentagons have 5 types. How many types are there for each form and what do they mean? I think I can get a 4x speedup but I don't want to post code I don't understand.

Is used to assist in the drawing, for example the type 0 has 5 rhombuses, the type 1 has 3 rhombuses, the thype 2 and 3, two rhombuses (left and right) and type 4 is used in the final corner.
The gray pentagon is the same thing: has 3 types. Type 0 is called in the beginning by the cyan pentagon type 0 (and then calls the "boat" and the two red pentagons), type 1 and 2 are used next to the cyan pentagon with three rhombuses, and type 3 is also called at the end. You can even comment on the line that calls these types so you can see how it will behave.

The "boat" is the same thing, but in the type 1, I needed to start drawing from the top.

Great job on making a reproducible example. I couldn't quite wrap my head
around the tiling algorithm - you might want to formalize it to leverage reasoning / insights for performance. If there is a way to eliminate the use of splice
for overlapping yellow rhombi, I think that would be a good start.
Here are the suggestions I came up with:

Split into two files: one for JavaScript and one for HTML. This makes editing easier.
Group operations - data.unshift(1, 2, 3) is faster than data.unshift(i) x3.
Reverse mainList. You can replace unshift with push and replace pop with an advancing index. This avoids the copying of unshift.
As a bonus, the vertex data is kept for debugging.
Global variables (and excess scope in general) can reduce readability. To reveal optimization opportunities, I would only use globals for constants.
In general, minimize duplication.
Many of the if statements can be handled in functions.
In theory, const is faster than let and var.
Consistent naming can reveal optimization opportunities. I renamed
mainList to roots, formVertex to root, size to sideLength,
and forms to shapeByMode.
Shape lookup appears to be the biggest bottleneck
based on the Chrome DevTools Performance Panel. To speed this up,
I first replaced cases of shapes.findIndex(...) >= 0 with shapes.some(...).
Second, I stored shapes in separate lists by their mode
(using identificator and type).
Third, I observed that a vertex v cannot be part of a shape if the distance
from v to any vertex in the shape is more than 3 * sideLength. This
is due to the shapes of the tiles and can be used to quickly prune shapes in the search.
I revised the switch statement to include a default that
errors on invalid values. I recommend similar error checking on form and type to improve understanding for others.

Here is my attempt at the HTML file:
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Penrose Tiling - P1</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="penrose.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

Here is my attempt at the JavaScript file:
// parameters to edit the shape formed
const maxLayerAmount = 40;
const sideLength = 1.3;

// setup function for p5.js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(2000, 2000);
}

// NAMING APPROACH
// vertex (v): {x, y}
// shape: vertex[]
// shapes: shape[]

// root: {x, y, angle, form, type}
// roots: root[]
const tolerance = 0.00001;

// whether a shape includes a vertex v
function include(shape, v) {
    for (let i = 0; i < shape.length; ++i) {
        const dx = Math.abs(shape[i].x - v.x);
        if (dx > 3 * sideLength)
            return false;

        const dy = Math.abs(shape[i].y - v.y);
        if (dy > 3 * sideLength)
            return false;

        if (dx < tolerance && dy < tolerance)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// whether some shape of a mode includes vertex v
function shapesModeSome(shapeByMode, mode, v) {
    return shapeByMode[mode].some(shape => {
        return include(shape, v);
    });
}

// index the first shape of a mode to include target
function shapesModeIndex(shapeByMode, mode, v) {
    return shapeByMode[mode].findIndex(shape => {
        return include(shape, v);
    });
}

const radianFactor = 3.141592653589793 / 180;

// the vertex found by moving at an angle from v 
function travel(v, degAngle) {
    const radAngle = degAngle * radianFactor;
    return {
        x: v.x + sideLength * cos(radAngle),
        y: v.y - sideLength * sin(radAngle)
    };
}

// does travel(root, a) for a in degAngles
// note: mutates root.angle
function travelShape(root, degAngles) {
    const shape = [{ x: root.x, y: root.y }];

    for (let i = 0; i < degAngles.length; ++i) {
        root.angle += degAngles[i];
        shape.push(travel(shape[i], root.angle));
    }

    return shape;
}

// uses p5.js to draw a shape
function drawForm(shape) {
    beginShape();
    for (let i = 0; i < shape.length; ++i)
        vertex(shape[i].x, shape[i].y);
    endShape(CLOSE);
}

// draw function for p5.js
function draw() {
    const startTime = performance.now();
    translate(width / 2, height / 2);

    let startAngle = 18;
    const hipotenuse = sideLength / (2 * sin(36 * radianFactor));
    let pentagonVertex = new Array(5);
    const roots = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pentagonVertex[i] = {
            x: hipotenuse * cos(startAngle * radianFactor),
            y: hipotenuse * -sin(startAngle * radianFactor)
        };

        roots.push(
            { x: pentagonVertex[i].x, y: pentagonVertex[i].y, angle: startAngle - 18, form: 0, type: 1 },
            { x: pentagonVertex[i].x, y: pentagonVertex[i].y, angle: startAngle + 162, form: 2, type: 0 }
        );
        startAngle += 72;
    }
    fill('cyan');
    drawForm(pentagonVertex);

    // 7 modes: form 1 (modes 0-4), form 0 (mode 5), form 5 (mode 6)
    const shapeByMode = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        shapeByMode.push([]);

    // loop variables
    let amount = 0;
    let my_limit = 0;
    let layerAmount = 0;
    let rhombusVertex;
    let boatVextex;
    let starVertex;

    // reverse mainList to make roots
    let next_root_i = 0;
    while (next_root_i < roots.length) {
        const root = roots[next_root_i];
        ++next_root_i;

        switch (root.form) {
            case 0: // root for yellow rhombus
                if (shapesModeSome(shapeByMode, 5, root))
                    break;

                rhombusVertex = travelShape(root, [0, 36, 144]);
                if (root.type > 1) {
                    let auxiliar = shapesModeIndex(shapeByMode, 5, rhombusVertex[1]);
                    if (auxiliar < 0)
                        auxiliar = shapesModeIndex(shapeByMode, 5, rhombusVertex[3]);

                    if (auxiliar >= 0) {
                        shapeByMode[5].splice(auxiliar, 1);
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                shapeByMode[5].push(rhombusVertex);
                roots.push({ x: rhombusVertex[2].x, y: rhombusVertex[2].y, angle: root.angle + 72, form: 1, type: root.type });
                fill('yellow');
                drawForm(rhombusVertex);
                break;
            case 1: // root for cyan pentagon
                pentagonVertex = travelShape(root, [72, 72, 72, 72]);
                if (root.type === 0) {
                    if (shapesModeSome(shapeByMode, 0, root)) {
                        roots.push(
                            { x: pentagonVertex[1].x, y: pentagonVertex[1].y, angle: root.angle + 72, form: 0, type: 1 },
                            { x: pentagonVertex[2].x, y: pentagonVertex[2].y, angle: root.angle + 144, form: 0, type: 1 },
                            { x: pentagonVertex[3].x, y: pentagonVertex[3].y, angle: root.angle + 216, form: 0, type: 1 },
                            { x: pentagonVertex[4].x, y: pentagonVertex[4].y, angle: root.angle + 288, form: 0, type: 1 }
                        );
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (amount === my_limit) {
                        layerAmount++;
                        if (layerAmount > maxLayerAmount) {
                            if (shapesModeSome(shapeByMode, 4, root)) {
                                roots.push(
                                    { x: root.x, y: root.y, angle: root.angle - 36, form: 2, type: 3 },
                                    { x: pentagonVertex[4].x, y: pentagonVertex[4].y, angle: root.angle + 252, form: 2, type: 3 }
                                );
                            }
                            else {
                                fill('cyan');
                                drawForm(pentagonVertex);
                            }
                            shapeByMode[4].push(pentagonVertex);
                            break;
                        }
                        amount = 0;
                        my_limit += 5;
                    }
                    amount++;
                    roots.push(
                        { x: pentagonVertex[0].x, y: pentagonVertex[0].y, angle: root.angle + 180, form: 2, type: 0 },
                        { x: pentagonVertex[1].x, y: pentagonVertex[1].y, angle: root.angle + 252, form: 2, type: 0 },
                        { x: pentagonVertex[2].x, y: pentagonVertex[2].y, angle: root.angle + 324, form: 2, type: 0 },
                        { x: pentagonVertex[3].x, y: pentagonVertex[3].y, angle: root.angle + 36, form: 2, type: 0 },
                        { x: pentagonVertex[4].x, y: pentagonVertex[4].y, angle: root.angle + 108, form: 2, type: 0 }
                    );
                }
                else if (root.type === 1) {
                    roots.push(
                        { x: pentagonVertex[2].x, y: pentagonVertex[2].y, angle: root.angle + 144, form: 0, type: 3 },
                        { x: pentagonVertex[3].x, y: pentagonVertex[3].y, angle: root.angle + 216, form: 0, type: 2 }
                    );
                }
                else if (root.type === 2) {
                    if (shapesModeSome(shapeByMode, 3, root))
                        continue;
                    if (shapesModeSome(shapeByMode, 1, pentagonVertex[1]))
                        continue;
                    roots.push({ x: pentagonVertex[3].x, y: pentagonVertex[3].y, angle: root.angle + 216, form: 0, type: 0 });
                }
                else {
                    if (shapesModeSome(shapeByMode, 2, root))
                        continue;
                    if (shapesModeSome(shapeByMode, 1, pentagonVertex[3]))
                        continue;
                    roots.push({ x: pentagonVertex[2].x, y: pentagonVertex[2].y, angle: root.angle + 144, form: 0, type: 0 });
                }
                shapeByMode[root.type].push(pentagonVertex);
                fill('cyan');
                drawForm(pentagonVertex);
                break;
            case 2: // root for gray pentagon
                pentagonVertex = travelShape(root, [72, 72, 72, 72]);
                if (root.type < 4) {
                    if (root.type === 0) {
                        roots.push(
                            { x: pentagonVertex[2].x, y: pentagonVertex[2].y, angle: root.angle + 108, form: 3, type: 3 },
                            { x: pentagonVertex[3].x, y: pentagonVertex[3].y, angle: root.angle + 252, form: 4, type: 0 },
                            { x: pentagonVertex[4].x, y: pentagonVertex[4].y, angle: root.angle + 108, form: 3, type: 3 }
                        );
                    }
                    else {
                        if (root.type == 3) {
                            if (!shapesModeSome(shapeByMode, 6, pentagonVertex[2]))
                                continue;
                            roots.push({ x: pentagonVertex[2].x, y: pentagonVertex[2].y, angle: root.angle - 36, form: 3, type: 3 });
                        }
                        roots.push({ x: pentagonVertex[2].x, y: pentagonVertex[2].y, angle: root.angle + 108, form: 3, type: root.type });
                    }
                }
                fill('gray');
                drawForm(pentagonVertex);
                break;
            case 3: // root for red pentagon
                pentagonVertex = travelShape(root, [72, 72, 72, 72]);
                if (root.type < 3) {
                    if (root.type === 0)
                        roots.push({ x: pentagonVertex[1].x, y: pentagonVertex[1].y, angle: root.angle + 108, form: 5, type: 1 });
                    else if (root.type === 1)
                        roots.push({ x: root.x, y: root.y, angle: root.angle + 324, form: 4, type: 1 });
                    else
                        roots.push({ x: pentagonVertex[3].x, y: pentagonVertex[3].y, angle: root.angle + 180, form: 4, type: 1 });
                }
                fill('red');
                drawForm(pentagonVertex);
                break;
            case 4: // root for green boat
                if (root.type === 0) {
                    if (shapesModeSome(shapeByMode, 6, root))
                        continue;
                    boatVextex = travelShape(root, [-36, -72, 144, 36, 36, 144]);
                    roots.push(
                        { x: boatVextex[2].x, y: boatVextex[2].y, angle: root.angle + 324, form: 2, type: 1 },
                        { x: boatVextex[3].x, y: boatVextex[3].y, angle: root.angle, form: 3, type: 0 },
                        { x: boatVextex[5].x, y: boatVextex[5].y, angle: root.angle + 324, form: 2, type: 2 }
                    );
                }
                else {
                    if (shapesModeSome(shapeByMode, 5, root))
                        continue;
                    boatVextex = travelShape(root, [36, 144, -72, 144, -72, 144]);
                    roots.push(
                        { x: boatVextex[1].x, y: boatVextex[1].y, angle: root.angle + 180, form: 2, type: 4 },
                        { x: boatVextex[2].x, y: boatVextex[2].y, angle: root.angle + 324, form: 3, type: 3 },
                        { x: boatVextex[3].x, y: boatVextex[3].y, angle: root.angle, form: 2, type: 4 },
                        { x: boatVextex[4].x, y: boatVextex[4].y, angle: root.angle + 36, form: 3, type: 3 }
                    );
                }
                fill('green');
                drawForm(boatVextex);
                break;
            case 5: // orange star
                const new_vertex = travel(root, root.angle + 72);
                if (shapesModeSome(shapeByMode, 6, new_vertex))
                    continue;
                starVertex = travelShape(root, [72, -72, 144, -72, 144, -72, 144, -72, 144]);
                shapeByMode[6].push(starVertex);
                fill('orange');
                drawForm(starVertex);
                break;
            default:
                throw "Invalid form!"
        }
    }
    const finalTime = performance.now();
    console.log("Time spent: " + ((finalTime - startTime) / 1000) + " seconds.");
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        console.log("found", shapeByMode[i].length, "shapes of mode", i);
    noLoop();
}

With sideLength = 1.3 and maxLayerAmount = 40, I timed 22.251 seconds vs 243.021 seconds, a substantial speed improvement. Hope this helps!

WOOOOWW!!! Thanks a lot! Your optimization was extremely fast and great!!! I will share the code on youtube one day and I will mention you that helped me with this!! Thanks a lot!
